# Permalink will not change - it wants to have -2 slug

Tags: permalinks

The issue was described in 1 or 2 post already but my case goes little more, since none of the mentioned causes are not my case:

- I do not have trash
- I checked my media and galleries
- Putting a ridiculous name (like: "2015555555" in stead of 2015) still produce "2015555555-2"

  Do not know what to do next...

Comment: Basically, *any* number in the first permastruct might conflict with a year, so if your permalink settings are `/%postname%/` then *every* integer-only title is going to be interpreted as a potential conflict with year-based archives and will get a suffix appended.

Answer (score 1):

Some things that come to mind to try:

Does this happen for all post types or just `post` or just custom post types? Are they hierarchical posts?

You could read through the wp_unique_post_slug function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/) to see what might be triggering the suffix.

Take a look through your database to see if there is any lingering post_meta that might be causing the duplicates (meta key = _wp_desired_post_slug).

See if there are any hooks that alter `wp_unique_post_slug`.

If you have a post with the slug 201555555-2 and you add a new post with the slug 201555555 does it get a -3? Is the -2 only added to number -only post titles or every post title even with only letters?

Comment: I believe a second 201555555 should produce a slug containing 201555555-3

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The suffix is added in a do while loop and is incremented. Corrected above.